# Проблема с присвоением значения элементам двумерного массива

Tags: python

Проблема  с присвоением значений в двумерном массиве self.P. При проверке по ходу итераций выводятся правильные числа. При попытке же вывести массив после окончания работы алгоритма в каждом "столбце" все значения одинаковы.

```
    def algo(self):
        for t in range(N*2):
            for i in range(N):
                for j in range(N):
                    if i != j:
                        b = self.pheromones[(i, j)]
                        #print(i,j)
                        self.P[i][j] = ((b[0] ** self.a) * (1 / self.distance(i, j)) ** self.b) / (self.sum(j))
                        print(i,j,self.P[i][j])
                        print("______________")

            self.update_phero()
            self.update_bridges()
         for i in range(N):
             print(self.P[i])
```

вот сам вывод

[Изображение](https://prnt.sc/itZ-snekST5r)

Comment: Всегда рекомендуется включать в вопросы минимальный пример выполняемого кода (ваш код не запустить, это только функция), а также конкретные тестовые примеры. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Упростил код до примера ниже. Он выдает разные данные по столбцам, то есть проблема ушла.

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 0, 6]
[0, 3, 6, 0]
```

Рекомендую для начала убрать `self.update_phero()` и `self.update_bridges()`, так как проверочную печать вы делаете до них (что в них делается, вы не указали в вопросе, так что совет на базе чистой логики и рабочего кода ниже). Если проблема уйдет - анализируйте, что не так в одной из этих функций.

```
def algo():
    P = [[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0]]
    for t in range(4 * 2):
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                if i != j:
                    P[i][j] = i*j
                    print(i, j, P[i][j])
                    print("______________")
    for i in range(4):
        print(P[i])

algo()
```

Comment: если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: self.update_phero() и self.update_bridges() уже убирал, дело не в них

Comment: 1) запустите мой код и убедитесь, что результат совпадает у вас с моим. 
2) если совпадает, то начинайте по частям добавлять удалённые компоненты и отследите, когда проблема вновь возникнет. Или помещайте воспроизводимый код.

Comment: Для 2 я бы советовал последовательность (проверять после каждого шага, что проблема не вернулась): 1) перевести мой код в `self`; 2) восстановить вычисления по формуле; 3) вернуть N; 4) вернуть две функции, в которых нет проблемы.